# Use class method to remove self from state array

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a card game using React and I'd like to move a card from the 'hand' state to the 'board' state. Both states are arrays. Here is my code so far...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {

  const [hand, setHand] = useState([])
  const [board, setBoard] = useState([])

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.cardName.value)
    let card = new Cards(event.target.cardName.value[0], event.target.cardName.value[1], "name")
    setHand(hand => [...hand, card])
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  const test = () => {
    console.log("hand =", hand)
    console.log("board =", board)
  }

  class Cards {
    constructor(suit, number, owner){
      this.suit = suit
      this.number = number
      this.owner = owner
    }

    play(){
     
      //Function that removes this object from the hand state          


      //Adding to the board array works fine
      setBoard(board => [...board, this])
    }

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="cardName" placeholder="Suit + Number"></input>
        <button type="submit">Create Card</button>
      </form>
      <button onClick={test}>test</button>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: "green", minWidth: 500, minHeight: 80}}>
        {hand.map(card => <div class="card" onClick={() => card.play()}>{card.suit+card.number}</div>)}
      </div>
      <div style={{backgroundColor: "red", minWidth: 500, minHeight: 80}}>
        {board.map(card => <div class="card" onClick={() => card.play()}>{card.suit+card.number}</div>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can't seem to access the 'hand' state without using the 'setHand()' method, so I can't set the hand as a new array with this instance removed. I also can't get the index of this instance without access to the 'hand' state.

A card can be created by typing something like 'D5' into the form and pressing submit. This adds a new card to the 'hand' state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first: in the handleSubmit method you can only do

```
setHand([...hand, card])
```

if you want to have access to the state of App inside the cards class u either need to pass it and handler related to it, so extra params on the class, passing the current state and methods to update the state from inside the Cards class, or you have the play method in the App, rather than the cards class.

Comment: The handle submit setHand works fine. It actually makes more sense to have 'play(card)' defined outside the Cards class and the method for the cards class call play and pass 'this'. This is a valid solution, but I'm going to leave it open, as I'd rather the 'play' method was inside the Cards class.

Comment: I didn't say that setHand was wrong, I was just stating you could do it just as well like that. I understand your request, though. good luck :)